# mysql container created but no default db

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

My `docker-compose.yaml`

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

My `.env`

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
MYSQL_DATABASE=buckets_db
MYSQL_USER=buckets_user
MYSQL_PASSWORD=buckets_password
```

I started all

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate -d
```

I can succesfully log into mysql via adminer using `root` as user and `secret` as password, as stated into my `.env` file

[image]

But as you can see, no `buckets_db` created

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that mysql container is creating db only if volume with its data is empty.

So I removed the container and the volume and recreated it